# Gaussian curvature is zero along the tangent intersection?

Tags: differential-geometry

Suppose a regular surface is tangent to a plane along a regular curve. How can I prove that the Gaussian curvature is zero along points of intersection between the surface and the plane?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The principal directions of the surface at a point of tangency of the surface will be in the direction of the tangent to the curve and perpendicular to the tangent to the curve. The curvature in the direction of the curve is $0$ since the curve lies in a plane. The Gaussian curvature, being the product of the principal curvatures will therefore be $0$.

Comment: To elaborate slightly, the normal vector $\mathbf n$ to the surface is constant along the curve, so $d\mathbf n_p(\mathbf v) = \mathbf 0$ at any point $p$ of the curve, with $\mathbf v$ the tangent vector to the curve. This means $\mathbf v$ is an eigenvector of the shape operator (principal direction) with eigenvalue (principal curvature) $0$.